# CSS - white-space:nowrap isn't preventing line break

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So I am trying to put a progress bar and a button in a button in the same line but for some reason, it doesn't work

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary text-nowrap" style="white-space:nowrap;">
        cpu usage procentage:  <span class="badge badge-light live text-nowrap" id ="cpu" style="white-space:nowrap;">{{computer.cpu_usage_procentage}}</span>  
      </button>
    <div class="progress">
      <div id="cpu-progress" class="progress-bar bg-danger" role="progressbar" style="width: {{computer.cpu_usage_procentage}}%" aria-valuenow="{{computer.cpu_usage_procentage}}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">{{computer.cpu_usage_procentage}}</div>
    </div>
```

[image: it look like this]

What I want is them to be in the same line instead of different lines so I saw that `white-space:nowrap;` should do the work but for some reason, it still doesn't work

Comment: because div is a `block` element you have to make it `inline` or `inline-block`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

white-space relates to text wrapping. this is two elements.

add this to the css:

```
.progress {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, works great. I'll accept it as soon as I can (12 minutes wait)